# Point Cloud Library - Writing functions to accept multiple types

Tags: point-cloud-library

```
static pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr extractConcaveHull(
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr inputCloud,
    double alpha
);
```

This function for example. Instead of writing two function calls, one for PointXYZ and one for PointXYZRGB and one for PointXYZRGBNormal, is there a way I can use some generic type? Like a PointCloud object, and on compile time it is able to cast accordingly

Answer (score -2):

This should work (I have not tested it).

```
template<typename POINT_TYPE>
static typename pcl::PointCloud<POINT_TYPE>::Ptr 
extractConcaveHull(
    typename pcl::PointCloud<POINT_TYPE>::Ptr inputCloud,
    double alpha
);
```

You can also pass by reference

```
template<typename POINT_TYPE>
static void 
extractConcaveHull(
    const typename pcl::PointCloud<POINT_TYPE>::Ptr& inpCloud,
    const typename pcl::PointCloud<POINT_TYPE>::Ptr& outCloud,
    double alpha
);
```

You are gonna have to define templated methods in your header file.

Comment: test before answer